# Kivy, Eclipse and PyDev (also PyPy)

Tags: eclipse, pydev, pypy, kivy

According to this post: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/kivy-users/n7c3thksnzg, it is possible to use Eclipse as an IDE for Kivy through PyDev. However, I didn't understand the instructions. Can anyone please elaborate on how to connect Kivy with Eclipse.

Note: I'm on a Windows machine. Also, is it possible to use PyPy instead of the Python Interpreter?

Thanks~!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Using Kivy with Pydev on Windows xp/7

- Under Window/Preferences/PyDev/Interpreter-Python add a new interpreter pointing to the python executable which ships with kivy portable
- add kivy package folder under libraries tab (still in Python Interpreters Prefs section making sure the kivy python interpreter is selected)
- In Environment tab, add the following three key-value pairs:
  (assumptions: kivy root is c:\kivy)

  GST_REGISTRY = c:\kivy\gstreamer\registry.bin

  GST_PLUGIN_PATH = c:\kivy\gstreamer\lib\gstreamer-0.10

  PATH = c:\kivy;c:\kivy\Python;c:\kivy\gstreamer\bin;c:\kivy\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
- When creating a new project intended to use kivy, just specify the appropriate interpreter and you should be ready to go

Comment: The above instructions are correct for getting Kivy to *run* from PyDev, but what took me ages to figure out was how to get PyDev to find Kivy at edit time. I.e., here is how to get rid of the import errors: **1)** It would seem that you can't have it installed like `C:\Kivy\Kivy-1.4.1`. I was having weird problems getting it working until I moved it to just `C:\Kivy141`. **2)** PyDev doesn't seem to find libraries that are located outside of the Python install directory, so you should either copy `C:\Kivy141\kivy\kivy` into `C:\Kivy141\Python\Lib\site-packages`, or make an equivalent symlink.

Comment: What resolved the issue of PyDev not finding the kivy package and thus flagging `import kivy` as an error was to place kivy in the list of forced builtins in the PyDev editor preferences.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's just pointing that:

- The PATH, GST_PLUGIN_PATH, GST_REGISTRY environment variables must be set (which you can actually do on the command line and then start up eclipse from that command line, or set in the interpreter configuration in the environment tab): http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html.
- Kivy must be added to the PYTHONPATH somehow. If you want, you can add it only to a project (as pointed in the post -- see: http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html) or to the actual interpreter configuration if more projects will share that: http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html.

Comment: After poking around (opening the kivy.bat script helped a lot), I figured it all out :) Thanks!

Also, It seems that Kivy does not support PyPy yet :(

Comment: Note: just added detailed instructions at: http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/configuring-kivy-on-pydev.html for configuring Kivy on PyDev

Answer (score 4):

After following instructions above I was still having problems with imports not found. I found I had to open my project's properties in Eclipse and under "PyDev - PYTHONPATH" add my kivy directory, e.g. C:\Kivy141\kivy

Comment: I see this post is a year old, but this should REALLY be added to the answer. This not only removed import errors but enabled auto-complete for me. WOOT!

Answer (score 3):

As of kivy 1.9.0, PATH must also include c:\kivy\SDL2\bin or else when trying to run kivy will throw an error and fail at opening a window. I Think I read that kivy no longer use PyGame and shifted to SDL2 since the answer posted in april 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 7 x64 with Eclipse Mars(release 4.5.1).
The steps that worked for me(very close to Rabih answer):

**1.** I copied Kivy 1.9.0 on my local machine from [here](http://kivy.org/#download)
**2.** I renamed the kivy.bat file to python.bat(this step can be ignored) 
**3.** Eclipse->Window->Preferences->PyDev->Interpreters->Python Interpreter->New

and added the python.bat file as interpreter. After doing this the interpreter should look like in the image:[image]

**4.** In the Environement tab add the 3 keys everybody mentioned:
GST_REGISTRY = c:\kivy\gstreamer\registry.bin
GST_PLUGIN_PATH = c:\kivy\gstreamer\lib\gstreamer-0.10
PATH = c:\kivy;c:\kivy\Python;c:\kivy\gstreamer\bin;c:\kivy\MinGW\bin;%PATH%
**5.** Use the interpreter that you just created in your project. Note that a default one will be selected if you don't specify the one you created

Answer (score 0):

## Using Eclipse IDE with Kivy and Pydev on OS X

- Type `which ivy` in the terminal and locate the executable (it should be /usr/local/bin/kivy)
- Then choose Preferences from Eclipse menu and navigate to PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter.
- Open the Select Interpreter dialog by clicking on the New... button (1) on the right.
- Fill the name of interpreter (kivy) in the Interpreter Name field (2)
- Fill the identified path (/usr/local/bin/kivy) in the Interpreter Executable field
- Press OK and wait till the process will be done.
- Do not forget to change interpreter settings in your project. You can do it by right click on your project in the Package Explorer under the PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar page.

[image]

Comment: I did as you suggested. But when running the app, I get an error that is:<b>
 File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Frameworks/python/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/script: line 9: /venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory
/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/script: line 39: /python: No such file or directory
/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/script: line 39: exec: /python: cannot execute: No such file or directory
<b>
Can you plz point out what I am missing?