# Installing kivy with pydev on a mac

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev, kivy

I am totally dead in the water right now. I'm trying to install kivy in pydev (eclipse) on a mac. I cannot get pydev to recognize kivy (I'm getting an import error - 'No module named kivy'. I've spent many hours reading every post on this subject. Almost all of them address Windows. The very few that address Macs are very sparse in their directions. The best directions that I can find are these:

> 1. install PyDev
> 2. manually add kivy package (compiled one, not the .dmg for mac) to python packages (done in Eclipse -> preferences -> PyDev ->
>      interpreters)
> 3. rebuild the package repository for interpreter (done in Eclipse -> preferences -> PyDev -> interpreters)
>
> => viola !

but they don't really explain how to accomplish this. Step one is easy. I need to know HOW to accomplish step 2 - not just be told to do it! Can anyone tell me how????

I know that I need to get a Python interpreter set up that includes a reference to kivy. I've copied my kivy folder into the python path, and added that path to pydev, but it's not working. Here's an image of my interpreter window in eclipse. It's not very informative, other than that you can see that it's set up incorrectly.

[image]

Thanks for any help. Please be detailed - I understand the main idea, but it's the execution that I am stuck on.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768489/kivy-eclipse-and-pydev-also-pypy ?

Comment: Yep. That post addresses Windows. I need help with Mac.

Comment: The steps should be the same... I think that the problem is that you're pointing to the default system python interpreter and not the one that ships with kivy as in that question.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question is one year old, but when faced with the same problem today, I could not find a clear answer. So, I'm leaving here my solution, just in case someone might find it useful:

In the terminal, introduce `which kivy`, so you will get the link to the kivy wrapper, which most likely will be at /usr/local/bin/kivy. You can then introduce this address in the field "Interpreter executable", and PyDev will automatically present you the proper library folders to select. With that, you should have set the new kivy interpreter.

Comment: did as you suggested. But when running the app, I get an error that is:<b> File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Frameworks/python/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 176 file=sys.stderr) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/script: line 9: /venv/bin/activate: No such file or directory /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/script: line 39: /python: No such file or directory /Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/script: line 39: exec: /python: cannot execute: No such file or directory <b> Can you plz point out what I am missing?