# configure kivy path in pydev eclipse (Debian)

Tags: linux, eclipse, pydev, kivy

I´d like to set pydev in eclipse for python library called kivy.

Problem is what to fill in interpreter executable. I can´t find right path.
I use Debian.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a user maintained list on the wiki of how to setup kv language in PyDev and other popular IDEs.
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE%27s

Furthermore the new release of Pydev is supposed to suport kvlanguage out of the box.
http://pydev.blogspot.in/2014/01/new-pydev-release-improved-indexing.html

This was also previously answered on SO @[Kivy, Eclipse and PyDev (also PyPy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768489/kivy-eclipse-and-pydev-also-pypy)

Comment: Note: just added some instructions on http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2014/02/configuring-kivy-on-pydev.html on how to configure Kivy with PyDev.