# Using Kivy on Eclipse Indigo, Ubuntu 10.04 & Python 2.7

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, ubuntu-10.04, kivy

I would like to use Kivy on Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu 10.04. I understand that python 2.7 is required (2.6 is the default on 10.04) and have python 2.7 installed as well. I've done lots of research but not found an answer. Can I do this and if so how? I don't want to upgrade ubuntu nor Eclipse since this would probably destabilise existing developments.

Comment: So what have you tried? What doesn't work? Also, if upgrading your OS and IDE will break existing development environments, you might want to reexamine the way you set up those environments.

Comment: If you want to build Kivy programs using Eclipse, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10387486/1917648) might help. I've not used Eclipse much, but I use Aptana Studio (which is based on Eclipse) for developing, building and running Kivy programs. It's obviously for Windows, but could be useful for Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 1):

Kivy and Eclipse are not related, and Eclipse is not necessary for running or editing Kivy programs. I can help to answer the Kivy part of your question, and will leave Eclipse to others.

Since Ubuntu 10.04 is out of support, it's hard to tell which required system packages are not available. This will probably be the most tedious part of the process. For Kivy on Ubuntu 12.04 you need:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential mercurial git python2.7 python-dev ccache ffmpeg libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsmpeg-dev libsdl1.2-dev libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev zlib1g-dev unzip
```

Some of those packages will have different versions on Ubuntu 10.04. Hopefully they are all available in some form.

Next you need to bootstrap an up-to-date Python setuptools environment:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge -y python-virtualenv python-pip python-setuptools
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python2.7
rm -f setuptools*.zip
sudo easy_install-2.7 -U pip
```

Now you can install an up-to-date Cython:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge -y cython
sudo pip2.7 install -U cython
```

Next you can install an up-to-date NumPy, which is required for PyGame:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge -y python-numpy
sudo pip2.7 install -U numpy
```

Now you can install an up-to-date PyGame:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge -y python-pygame
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
cd pygame
python2.7 setup.py build
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
cd ..
sudo rm -rf pygame
```

Now that all of the dependencies are met, you can install an up-to-date Kivy:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge -y python-kivy
sudo pip install -U kivy
```